# What is the difference between App Settings and Configuration Settings in Azure DevOps Deploy WebApp task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps for the "Azure App Service Deploy" task there are 2 section under the Application and Configuration Settings:

[image]

With the hint being almost identical.

What is the difference between them?

If the later one refers to General settings of the web app, then why can you enter pretty much anything there?

Is it possible to enter Connection Strings somehow from this task?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sorry for the delay in response but I still hope someone finds this useful.

App settings are used to set the key value in app settings on the Azure portal however configuration settings are used for General settings. The Azure App Service Deploy does not support configuring connection strings. The configuration settings do not have a syntax because they can have a variety of values like a single value or an array, etc.

However, to clear the misconceptions we have added a new task called Azure App Service Settings which has three sections namely App Settings, General Settings and Connection Strings which clears all your doubts asked in this question.